# abp generate-proxy -t ng: skips with no proxy generations

Tags: angular, rest, asp.net-core, proxy, abp

I need help.

I am following the [abp framework tutorial part 2](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Part-2?UI=NG&DB=EF) it means the backend project is working correctly but when I start setting the Angular application there is a step that generates a proxy service using the next command:

```
abp generate-proxy -t ng
```

When you execute it, the cli asks the following: `? Please enter target Angular project to place the generated code. (default: workspace)`

The first time I executed it. I could type something. I typed **workspace** but that is not the correct name I guess. It would be the same name as the angular project in this case **Angular/**

The next time I wanted to set this name, the command skips unexpectedly and now I cannot change it and resume with the tutorial.

I created a new ABP project and just used the Angular project because I thought something in the Angular app is configured wrong but no. Now always the command skips unexpectedly and there is no useful documentation on the internet to solve this problem.

It should create a directory called proxy/books that contains some files as in the picture below:
[Service Proxy Generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQYLE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQYLE.png)

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the following command to fix this issue. As in Angular 14 default project property is deprecated.

ng generate @abp/ng.schematics:proxy-add --target=Your Project --source=Your Project

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your advice. I just created a new project and start again. But this might be helpful in the future.